# Why are the bots on my custom map not doing anything?

Tags: starcraft

Just made my first map on Staredit yesterday and tried to play it(I am playing remastered, 1.16.1), but the bots don't do anything. I'm pretty sure I did everything right. All the bots have drones they can use, and they are on a different team than the player, but even when attacked they don't do anything. No mining, no unit production, or anything you would normally see.

I don't know if it's relevant, but I don't have any vespene geysers by the bot bases(to keep them from getting air units. Eventually this will be moved into map settings by restricting the units). Is that maybe why it's broken?

Here are some pictures that might help;

Picture of enemies bases about 30 seconds into the game. They have done nothing.

[image: pic of enemies in game]

Picture of the force tab in StarEdit. All the Zerg bots are on different teams than the Terran player.

[image: force tab in staredit]

Picture of properties tab in StarEdit. All Zerg players are assigned computer control.

[image: properties tab in staredit]

I'm really confused as to why nothing is happening. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it do so for ANY custom map? I wonder if the map you created, for some reason, screws up the AI and the way the game reacts to that is just to throw its hands up and not do anything.

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't think so. I played 3 games on a fastest map I downloaded and that worked fine. I'll try making another custom map when I get home. Maybe it doesn't like the version of StarEdit or something.

Comment: Yeah if other maps work that is not the bot engine being completely down, its that there is something on your map that seemingly paralyzes it for that map only. I really wonder what tho.

Comment: So basically now the question is figure out what paralyzes it, and remove it and/or replace it with something that doesnt bug.

Comment: By the way: If you want easy screenshots, open imgur, and while having the screen active press 'print screen'. Then go into imgur and Ctrl+V, it will paste the screenshot there. Alt + Print Screen will only pick up the active window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC from my experience creating custom maps years ago, you need to create triggers for each faction that actually implement the AI type you want them to have.
Something like "Always" being the triggering condition, since you want the enemy to always run the AI, and then "Run AI" or "Run AI Type At location" or something similar, and choose the type of Zerg AI you want them to run, such as Easy, Medium or Hard from a dropdown.